# Why is my green tea yellow?

Tags: tea

I make Japanese green tea. I use Gyokuro Imperial, a high quality shaded green tea, so it should be green not yellow.

Sometimes when I make it, it is indeed green, but other times yellow.

Is it because I am putting too much tea in, or too little?

Answer (score 4):

Fresh Japanese green tea leaves (even after they're processed) should look green. The Japanese steam the leaves which is why the leaves maintain the green colour. However, you've to keep the green tea dry. If it's exposed for too long (or too often) to air and humidity, the leaves will start to oxidise and turn yellow. In such cases, it also often starts to loose it's aroma and flavour.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Addition: when you're referring to steeping, it's more about water temperature. Using hotter water will result in a more yellow brew. If you want more flavour, use more leaves, but keep the temperature down.